# What's the deal with this free hosting service?

Tags: web-hosting

A free webhosting service I am researching offers - free hosting.

What's the catch?

Sexy cPanel, fast loads. For free.

What's the deal here?

Free email, free ssh.

Are they going to come and harvest my kidneys in the night?

There about us page says:

> THEIR MISSION
>
> Serving consumers worldwide, this is a customer-centric service dedicated to serving the security needs of our customers. Simple Host Informática is a Brazilian company who operates site.com.br, one of the biggest “website builder” in Brazil. We are headquartered in Belo Horizonte-MG, Brazil, and operate our servers through a regional data center in Dallas, TX. As one of the leading IT and tech services companies in the industry, we have made it our mission to continue offering our effective and affordable free and professional web hosting packages that meet and exceed our customers’ needs.

Seems to be a little too good to be true kind-of-deal.

So, what's the deal?

Comment: Gee whizz, I hate the way they blatent keyword spam, puts me right off... "best web hosting, cheap web hosting, free hosting, free web hosting, free website hosting, Free WordPress Hosting, host, hosting, web host, web hosting, Web Hosting Services, webhosting, website hosting" (all link to different auto-generated pages with the stated keywords) - Also much hidden text under different sections, all stating the same nonsense in various ways / different keywords!

Comment: What is the catch? I don't know, but there is always one. Iframes are common along with other tricks. Be that as it may, you always get what you pay for. I suggest coughing up the few shinny coins it takes to host your site properly. Hosting has been sooooooo cheap for decades now, I do not see the point in shaving a few more lousy shekles.

Comment: Understand that there are a lot of good companies that charge $5-10 per month (and bad ones).  Also understand the absolute pain you will go through in transferring your account to a new provider once your site is live and has issues with this provider.  There are so many businesses like this that will throttle your site until it is unusable and then charge $500 to transfer.  I had to open a ticket with ICANN about 8 years ago and maybe it is easier now but it was a 2 month black hole and if the site was bigger it would have cost the owner tons of $$$... to save $5 a month.

Comment: @blankip Thanks for the personal experience. I was a web host and I cannot tell you how many people ran away to save a buck. What they missed out on was for the standard $9.95 they had direct access to MAEEAST, MAEWEST with redundant quad OC3 connections and satellite backup connections managed by the guy who spun and disassembled 5 major Internet backbones onto a new global network that he managed. With hot spares, spares on the shelf, spares in the air, and full redundancy across several servers, no host can offer this level of service still today. All to save a buck. Silly people! Sheesh!!

Comment: @closetnoc - never ever choose a host outside of your country... rule 1.  Maybe this is different in smaller countries or europe.  Rule 2... make sure they have a number that people actually pick up before you pay them.  Not a number that you leave a message.  Those are just two givens minus what they actually provide.

Comment: @blankip My technical support number rang the owners cell phones, myself and a friend I brought in as a partner. We were the technical support 24/7. It worked well since most people never actually had to call us. We had automation that solved most all problems immediately and transparently. For the rest, we had advanced monitors that allowed us to solve problems before anyone ever called us. I used to build *reliable systems* that could not go down and built neural networks before the term existed in the wild. It all worked well. Still, users could not see the advantages. Sad.

Answer (score 2):

> Seems to be a little too good to be true kind-of-deal.

It usually is, so you are right to question.

> Free email, free ssh.

- SSH is not available on the free plan.
- Email is advert supported (sent emails contain adverts). "Also, emails of free plans have less resources." - whatever that means?

Other limitations:

- 200MB storage
- No backups (paid plans only)
- No CRON Jobs (paid plans only)
- No support ticket system (paid plans only). (Knowledge base and Forums only - the Forums seem *very* quiet.)

Caveats

- Data center in Dallas, TX. (According to about page.) This might not be the right locale for you.
- There is reportedly still a charge of $0.01 ("to verify your identity"), so you are still required to enter payment information.

I see no information (for free or paid plans) about stated uptime or inode (number of files) limitations.